# ZF2 slow performance

Tags: zend-framework2

I am using zf2 on wamp on my lenovo yoga.  I am just wondering if I am getting greater than average load page times.  Zend developer tools give me the below load times (about 2sec).

1. Route1.38 s
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 290
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
2. Dispatch4.60 ms
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 309
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
3. Dispatch3.08 ms
   File: Controller/AbstractController.php - Line: 117
   Target: CsnCms\Controller\IndexController
4. Render652.94 ms
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 347
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
5. Renderer491.86 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 175
   Target: Zend\View\View
6. Renderer.Post604.15 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 185
   Target: Zend\View\View
7. Renderer419.86 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 175
   Target: Zend\View\View
8. Renderer.Post396.01 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 185
   Target: Zend\View\View
9. IsAllowed75.79 ms
   File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
   Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
10. IsAllowed838.04 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
11. IsAllowed684.98 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
12. IsAllowed743.15 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
13. IsAllowed761.99 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
14. IsAllowed620.84 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
15. IsAllowed744.10 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
16. IsAllowed913.86 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
17. IsAllowed948.19 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
18. IsAllowed702.86 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
19. Response4.25 ms
    File: View/View.php - Line: 216
    Target: Zend\View\View
20. Finish485.90 µs
    File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 348
    Target: Zend\Mvc\Application

It is a bit faster on my shared server

1. Route160.68 ms
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 290
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
2. Dispatch1.50 ms
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 309
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
3. Dispatch2.26 ms
   File: Controller/AbstractController.php - Line: 117
   Target: Trip\Controller\IndexController
4. Render512.00 ms
   File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 347
   Target: Zend\Mvc\Application
5. Renderer239.85 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 175
   Target: Zend\View\View
6. Renderer.Post182.15 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 185
   Target: Zend\View\View
7. Renderer204.80 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 175
   Target: Zend\View\View
8. Renderer.Post180.01 µs
   File: View/View.php - Line: 185
   Target: Zend\View\View
9. IsAllowed86.17 ms
   File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
   Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
10. IsAllowed366.93 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
11. IsAllowed365.97 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
12. IsAllowed353.10 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
13. IsAllowed270.84 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
14. IsAllowed341.18 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
15. IsAllowed622.99 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
16. IsAllowed357.87 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
17. IsAllowed380.04 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
18. IsAllowed493.05 µs
    File: Navigation/AbstractHelper.php - Line: 345
    Target: Zend\View\Helper\Navigation\Menu
19. Response2.82 ms
    File: View/View.php - Line: 216
    Target: Zend\View\View
20. Finish230.07 µs
    File: Mvc/Application.php - Line: 348
    Target: Zend\Mvc\Application

Is this what I should expect or is there a way i can speed things up.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask this, i couldn't find anything on the net to show me what i should expect.

Comment: are you asking if ZF2 is slow in general or when comparing to your shared server?

Comment: Its normal to have fast shared server compare to your localhost, After they have high end servers with very much optimized environment.

Comment: This is worth a watch for zf2 optimisation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwpGPlL8oZc&list=PL_aPVo2HeGF-7o9SPO5arFrAaU8bcIjba&index=25

Comment: Thanks Jon Day, I will watch it.  The main thing i was looking for was to know if they are normal load times or should I be expecting something faster.